# Bing map covered the Title Panel!Why?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I put a MapControl in a scrollviewer, but when I pulled up the MapControl, the MapControl covered the TitlePanel!Like this photo
[image]
How to fix this?Is it a system bug?Thx~~~

Here is My xaml code

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel 包含應用程式的名稱和頁面標題-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="我的應用程式" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="頁面名稱" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - 其他內容置於此-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Width="440" Height="258" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <msMap:Map x:Name="Map" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" ScaleVisibility="Collapsed"  CredentialsProvider="Al1klJ_w8MPrZ0kntZyMogTJkXb79xyNKVC2XpJuwSPp0NmAbrIuAthSzs5xbomJ">                        
                </msMap:Map>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is definitely some problem in your grid margins. If you paste your `xaml` code. Maybe I will be help you out in a more better way

**[Updated]**

Try: This is working for me.

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid MaxHeight="400" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <my:Map HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: even your code is working. With the scrollviewer. I dont find any mistake in the xaml.

Comment: might be. But i don't understand how its working for me and is not working for you

Comment: You need to put a scrollviewer, and add a MapControl in this scrollviewer.Your xaml code doesn't have a scrollviewer~

Comment: Updated my answer. It is not happening for the code which I have posted.